# How to add the chart in excel using handlebars?

Tags: javascript, excel, charts, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I need to add the chart in excel. From table data ,need a chart to be drawn in the excel.I have add xlsxAdd to append chart in excel, but its throwing **Missing helper: "xlsxAdd**
error. So table is already there in the excel but chart is not rendering using this handlebars.This is the correct way to add chart in excel ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Report</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table {
        width: 100%
    }

    td {
        text-align: center
    }
</style>
<body>
     <div>
        <img src="https://icicipruamcdev.azureedge.net/static/media/logo.86f7e0e9.svg" style="height: 150px;">
    </div>


    <canvas id="canvas" style="width:90vw"></canvas>
    <script>
         document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            // Extract data from the table
            const table = document.getElementById('report-table');
            const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
            const labels = [];
            const navData = [];
            rows.forEach((row, index) => {
                if (index > 0) { // Skip header row
                    const cells = row.querySelectorAll('td');
                    labels.push(cells[1].textContent); // Assuming date is in the second column
                    navData.push(parseFloat(cells[0].textContent)); // Assuming nav is in the first column
                }
            });
            
            // Chart data
            const chartData = {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: "NAV_HISTORY",
                    type: 'line',
                    data: navData,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    borderColor: 'blue',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    lineTension: 0,
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'blue',
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    borderColor: 'navy',
                    pointRadius: 3
                }]
            };

            // Chart initialization
            const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartData,
                options: {
                    responsive: false,
                    animation: false,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    devicePixelRatio: 1,
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                stepSize: 20
                            }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                autoSkip: true,
                                maxTicksLimit: 8,
                                maxRotation: 0,
                                minRotation: 0
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>   
    <div><br/></div>
    <div class="invoice-box">
       <!-- Assuming you have a table structure like this -->
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>NAV</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each data}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{this.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{this.Amount}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Now, let's add the xlsxAdd functionality -->
{{#xlsxAdd "xl/drawings/drawing1.xml" "xdr:wsDr.twoCellAnchor"}}
{{#each data}}
<row>
    <c t="inlineStr"><is><t>{{this.Name}}</t></is></c>
    <c><v>{{this.Amount}}</v></c>
</row>
{{/each}}
{{/xlsxAdd}}

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```